# HTML Helper in JavaScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, razor

In Razor I can do this:

```
<p @Html.MyCustomDataAttributeFor(person) >@person.Name</p>
```

To render something like this:

```
<p data-custom-person-id="1234567890" >Fred</p>
```

Must I really then do this in (unobtrusive) JavaScript:

```
$('p[data-custom-person-id="1234567890"]').css('background-color','red');
```

When I'd prefer to do this:

```
$('p[@Html.MyCustomDataAttributeFor(person)]').css('background-color','red');
```

If only I could, otherwise should the data attribute generated by the HTML helper change, my client side code will no longer style the element.

Comment: Is this javascript in a view file? What server side language are you using? If the JS is in a view file (where I'd assume your Razor code is) then you should be able to do what you want.

Comment: It's in a separate .js file

Comment: Then I don't believe you can do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you point the script to a .cshtml-file?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/myscript.cshtml"></script>
```

I think I've done this for both .php and .aspx so I don't see a reason it shouldn't work.
In those cases it makes the server first process the file.

Otherwise you could use a customer [`HttpHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that parses whatever text you want server-side before it's sent to the client.

The easiest however, would be to set some Javascript variables from Razor, ie:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var customerId = '@Html.MyCustomDataAttributeFor(person)';
</script>
```

And then write:

```
$('p[' + customerId + ']').css('background-color','red');
```

Answer (score 1):

`data-custom-person-id="1234567890"` is rendered to the browser after server has converted `@Html.MyCustomDataAttributeFor(person)` to that value. On the client side you will not be receiving these text at all. So, you cannot use those statements for client side styling.

Comment: You mean the razor output is once per request but the JavaScript is cached so hard coding is the only way?

Comment: @Grokodile Yes. Razor code is converted to Javascript code on server only and sent to the browser. So, you need to hard-code only